# Why aren't we (humans) affected from magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, biology

From what I understand humans has a capacitance and are able to store charge, and we also have a velocity, we know that the magnetic force is $\vec{F}=q\vec{v}\times \vec{B}$.

I assume while we standing on earth we are grounded so no net charge in our body, but what about while we fly in a plane? and what about birds? they spent their times moving with velocity in the air.

I hope my question is clear enough,
thank you

Comment: Flip it around: why should we be affected?  Or more specifically, what effects do you think you should see which you aren't?

Comment: we should be affected because we have net charge and velocity, and I guess we should feel a Force , like gravity but this force will have time dependent direction

Comment: Humans (as most of earthly matter) are electrically neutral, being made of non-ionized atoms.

Comment: Also it should be noted that the magnetic field of earth is very weak from our point of view, magnets stuck to your refrigerator are stronger than the Earth's field. Have you tried a back of the envelope calculation of the maximum possible force you could possibly perceive if you even carried one extra electron at say airplane speeds in Earth's field? You will find the number to be quite small.

Comment: @MauroGiliberti Cells contain many ions. Many biological process rely on ions.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Perhaps more precicely, we are electrically neutral as a whole, where any ion is typically paired with a corresponding ion of the opposite charge.

Comment: @CortAmmon I agree with that :)

Comment: The question is about the force from magnetic fields, which are negligible, but magnetic fields can still 'have an effect on' humans. The effect on charged particles from a magnetic field can be sensed by shaking your head inside an MRI.

Comment: @4xion As someone who's never been inside an MRI: please consider elaborating in an answer.

Comment: @BioPhysicist yeah you're right, sorry. I meant to say that, even with ions, we're globally neutral.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We are indeed affected by magnetic forces as you say.  They're just astonishingly weak.  We can actually calculate them!

Most of the time, our charge is so neutral that the story isn't any fun, so let's spice it up.  Lets hook you up to a Van de Graaff generator, raising your potential to 100kV.  That's enough to make a pretty darn impressive spark.  To figure out how much charge that actually is, we need to know the capacitance of the human body.  It's roughly 100pF, so if you're charged to 100kV, you have a charge of 100kV * 100pF = 0.00001 C (or 62,415,097,500,000 electrons, if you want to think of it that way).

Now we need a velocity.  Go big or go home.  Let's use the SR-71's top speed, which is pretty close to 1000m/s

The [earth's magnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field) is on the order of 50 micro-teslas.  $0.00001 \text C \times .00005\text T \times 1000 \text{m/s} = 0.0000000005 \text N  = 0.5 \text{nN}$

Needless to say, you don't notice many effects on the nano-newton level.  Especially when flying in a SR-71, hurtling through the air while hooked up to a Van De Graaff generator.

Comment: wow! this is really small, and what about the direction of the force? how can we calculate it? will it be time dependent?

Comment: @Sagigever The direction is always perpendicular to the velocity and the magnetic field.  So as you fly around, it will change direction a little, or if you turn the aircraft, it will change or get smaller.  My case was a maximum-force case where you were flying East.  Fly along the magnetic field lines, and the force is 0 (can you see why?)

Comment: This post should win the "visualisation of the week" award. Hands down.

Comment: Can we get Mythbusters to try this? Although a 100kV VdG is actually pretty small and cheap on Amazon (really).

Comment: @JonCuster I chose a desktop sized one.  They do get bigger.  We actually could have managed a few nano newtons had I chosen a [large one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95tq5J6ioF0).  Getting a SR-71 pilot to okay those guys doing their thing mid-flight could be more difficult.

Comment: My previous job included running a 6MV on terminal tandem VdG (EN tandem) designed by Robert J Van de Graaff himself that is older than me. The display model in the atrium of the lab was from Amazon...